# Cannot alter Bootstrap button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<button class="btn btn-default">Click me</button>
```

I want to alter this button by reducing it's padding to 0px, so I added an extra class `no-padding` in style.css

```
.no-padding {
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
}
```

and called it like

```
<button class="btn btn-default no-padding">Click me</button>
```

But still I'm getting the same class
and If I use inline style statement, it works perfectly, but I don't want to do it in that way

Thanks!!

Comment: Typo in `padding-rigt`

Comment: you need to tag bootstrap 4 or bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you need to know `specificity` concept of CSS

you can do like this

```
button.no-padding {
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-rigt: 0;
}
```

and your CSS works fine. You see difference in below snippet

```css
button.no-padding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.no-padding1 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-default no-padding">Click me</button>
<button class="btn btn-default no-padding1">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Nisharg, It was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to know, you like my answer

Comment: actually, this is the case of normal. But when you are using a bootstrap button, as I specified above, you have to write the style class as 
`btn-default.no-padding{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}`

Comment: btn-default is not tag, you cant write like that

Comment: if you right .btn-default.no-padiing specificity are increasing also but i think for this type of question, you don't want to be do it

Answer (score 1):

> You can use Bootstrap padding classes.
>
> 1 > px : padding at left and right. 2 > py : padding at top and
>   botton.
>
> See more examples given below

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Your Button as it is  :
<button class="btn btn-default ">Click me</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Button with px class :
<button class="btn btn-primary px-0">Click me</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Button with py class
<button class="btn btn-warning py-0">Click me</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Button with px and py class :
<button class="btn btn-success px-0 py-0">Click me</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Button with pl class
<button class="btn btn-danger pl-0">Click me</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Button with pr class :
<button class="btn btn-success pr-0">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash. Your answer seems to be a good one, but what I need was to solve the issue without using bootstrap classes. anyway thank you for the answer and it was a piece of new information for me.  I have voted your answer, but can't give the green tick, since the first answer was the one I was looking for.
Thank you for your support...!